# UWP Light dismiss ContentDialog

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

Is there a way to make the ContentDialog light dismiss?, so when the user clicks on any thing outside the ContentDialog it should be closed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

By default, **ContentDialog** is placed in **PopupRoot**. Behind it, there is a **Rectangle** which dim and prevent interaction with other elements in the app. You can find it with help of **VisualTreeHelper** and register a **Tapped** event to it, so when it's tapped you can hide **ContentDialog**.

You can do this after calling **ShowAsync** outside **ContentDialog** code or you can do it inside **ContentDialog** code. Personally, I implement a class which derives from **ContentElement** and I override **OnApplyTemplate** like this:

```
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    // this is here by default
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    // get all open popups
    // normally there are 2 popups, one for your ContentDialog and one for Rectangle
    var popups = VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups(Window.Current);
    foreach (var popup in popups)
    {
        if (popup.Child is Rectangle)
        {
            // I store a refrence to Rectangle to be able to unregester event handler later
            _lockRectangle = popup.Child as Rectangle;
            _lockRectangle.Tapped += OnLockRectangleTapped;
        }
    }
}
```

and in **OnLockRectangleTapped**:

```
private void OnLockRectangleTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    _lockRectangle.Tapped -= OnLockRectangleTapped;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `ContentDialog` does not offer such behavior.

There are two alternatives you can consider:

- [**Popup**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup) - a special control built for this purpose, which displays dialog-like UI on top of the app content. This control actually offers a `IsLightDismissEnabled` for the behavior you need. Since the Anniversary Update (SDK version 1607) also has a `LightDismissOverlayMode`, which can be set to "On" to automatically darken the UI around the Popup when displayed. More details are [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup).
- **Custom UI** - you can create a new layer on top of your existing UI in XAML, have this layer cover the entire screen and watch for the `Tapped` event to dismiss it when displayed. This is more cumbersome, but you have a little more control over how it is displayed